# React Native FlatList renders data twice when using extraData

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-flatlist

I am using React Native with firebase (without Redux or anything similar).
I have a FlatList listening to changes with firebase by using the 'on' method.
The FlatList ist listening to changes but when new Data gets rendered it renders the new data and the old data aswell. So I have the old data and then the old the data with the new data attached.

I retrieve the data like this:

```
firebase.database().ref(`/thisThat/${uid}/arguments/this/`).orderByChild('timestamp')
      .on('value', (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((child) => {
            thisArr.push(child.val());
        });
      this.setState({ thisArguments: thisArr });
    });
```

I am doing it this way because I want it to be ordered (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33897213/5075510)

My FlatList looks like this:

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.thisArguments}
  renderItem={this.renderItem}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
  ListEmptyComponent={this.emptyList}
  extraData={this.state}
 />
```

I think it propably has to do with the way I am retrieving the data. When I am doing it without the forEach everything works fine but it won't render ordered.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't know too much about Firebase but you are `push`ing all the data into `thisArr` every time you handle the event, which explains why data keeps getting appended. I think you need to reset the array before pushing, ie `thisArr = []`.

Comment: Yes that fixed the issue. Thank you very much for your comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to clear `thisArr` before you push new items to it

```
firebase.database().ref(`/thisThat/${uid}/arguments/this/`).orderByChild('timestamp')
.on('value', (snapshot) => 
{
    thisArr = [];   // <----- here is the fix
    snapshot.forEach((child) => 
    {
        thisArr.push(child.val());
    });

    this.setState({ thisArguments: thisArr });
});
```

Comment: I thought I arleady tried this but it seems like I didn't. Anyway it works now with your solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: happy to help you :)

Comment: Can check this question please @Ali https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57595796/how-to-force-flatlist-to-re-render-after-getting-a-single-data