# Firebase orderByChild not working as expected

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a DB in firebase with this structure (let's assume that the order in firebase is the same here):

```
"002f6b4a378caed3be3bd00346e3d380": {
  "id": "002f6b4a378caed3be3bd00346e3d380",
  "name": "Thayne",
  "date": 1516242371000,
  "totalDuration": 297
},
"8181554c6d4da1b7bfbb74aafe683b5d": {
  "id": "8181554c6d4da1b7bfbb74aafe683b5d",
  "name": "Marna",
  "date": 1517840087000,
  "totalDuration": 283
},
"d5d17675cae2b480020e0d43b9074658": {
  "id": "d5d17675cae2b480020e0d43b9074658",
  "name": "Clint",
  "date": 1515673469000,
  "totalDuration": 184
},
"9f2cdf88d59dd778d9aaa5745d10d1e2": {
  "id": "9f2cdf88d59dd778d9aaa5745d10d1e2",
  "name": "Nadia",
  "date": 1521918148000,
  "totalDuration": 234
},
"afc21c30da7b4ef3e88234cd7988f6a7": {
  "id": "afc21c30da7b4ef3e88234cd7988f6a7",
  "name": "Alexi",
  "date": 1519041073000,
  "totalDuration": 110
}
```

I have two int on each record, `date` and `totalDuration`, time  is a UNIX timestamp and duration just a number that goes between 30 and 350.

I want to retrieve the list of all elements ordered by either one of this numbers. Going through the API and the docs I'm trying this:

```
var orderRef = firebase.database().ref("elements/");

orderRef.orderByChild('totalDuration').on("value", function(data){
  var result = data.val();
  for ( id in result ) {
    console.log( result[id].totalDuration );
  }
});
```

I'm expecting this:

```
110
184
234
283
297
```

Instead I'm getting the same order it already exists in the database:

```
297
283
234
110
184
```

Same goes for the date, it returns the data in the same order it exists in the database.

I'd like to know if there's something wrong with: a) My code, or b) My conception of how `orderByChild` actually works.

Comment: I think this post would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33893866/orderbychild-not-working-in-firebase

Comment: Thanks @goblin, that does it. I was actually looking for a way to receive the data already ordered and not run extra code to add it to an object, but that'll do it certainly. Thanks again!!!