# Angular & Firebase: Get a list sorted by release date?

Tags: angular, firebase, sorting, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve a list of books sorted by release date, but... nothing seems to work. I'm working with Angular and Firebase.

There are some screenshots:

1. [My code to retrieve the list of books](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh3Ui.jpg)
2. [Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEMDk.jpg)

⇒ [What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7BNW.png)

As you can see, the last two books (without picture) are not before the Harry Potter ones. I don't understand how I can sort the list. I read a lot of time the Firebase doc, but... I don't know what to do.

Any idea? Hope you can help me!

Sylvester

Comment: see the answer here, seems that should fix your issue too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33893866/orderbychild-not-working-in-firebase

Comment: @slyraier - It would help if your code were not in a photo and was actually in your question.