# Async/Await function is never resolved with Dispatch

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise, dispatch

In my function below, `addToFlatList` is only called once, even though I know there are several items in my database to be added. Seems like the fist `addToFlatList` is never resolved? What am I doing wrong?

```
photosSnapshot.forEach(async function(childSnapshot) {
    await addToFlatList(childSnapshot.key, childSnapshot.val())(dispatch);
});
```

addToFlatList function:

```
const addToFlatList = (photoId, photoObj) => async(dispatch) => { 
    database.ref('users').child(photoObj.author).once('value').then((userSnapshot) => {
        var userInfo = userSnapshot.val();
        dispatch({type: "GOT_USER", payload: userInfo});
    }).catch(error => {
        dispatch({type: "GOT_ERROR"});
    });
}
```

**Update**:

Tried to return dispatch like this. `addToFlatList` is still only called once.

```
const addToFlatList = async(photoId, photoObj) => {
    return (dispatch) => { 
        database.ref('users').child(photoObj.author).once('value').then((userSnapshot) => {
            var userInfo = userSnapshot.val();
            dispatch({type: "GOT_USER", payload: userInfo});
        }).catch(error => {
            dispatch({type: "GOT_ERROR"});
        });
    }
}
```

Also tried this:

```
const addToFlatList = async(photoId, photoObj) => {
    database.ref('users').child(photoObj.author).once('value').then((userSnapshot) => {
        return (dispatch) => { 
          // never hit this point
          var userInfo = userSnapshot.val();
          dispatch({type: "GOT_USER", payload: userInfo});
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        dispatch({type: "GOT_ERROR"});
    });
}
```

Comment: Is your database _firebase_ by chance?

Comment: Your `addToFlatList` is marked as `async` but does neither `await` anything nor `return` a promise?

Comment: What do you mean by "never resolved"? Does it never continue to the next iteration of the `.forEach`?

Comment: @Bergi It implicitly resolves with `undefined` in the end of the async function.

Comment: @IvanRubinson Firebase. And it never continues to the next iteration. Seems like it is just waiting for something but dispatch is fired

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Comment: mmm so I should return the dispatch? Strange because the curried function implies dispatch will be returned right? And it is called in both the success and failure cases

Comment: @IvanRubinson And that's a problem, because that doesn't wait for the database or the dispatch.

Comment: @Bergi the reason I made `addToFlatList` async is because the order of the photos being added to the feed matters

Comment: @JAM Just marking it as `async` doesn't change anything. You need to ensure that you return a promise for whatever you want to wait for.

Comment: @Bergi doesn't the arrow in `database.ref('users').child(photoObj.author).once('value').then((userSnapshot) => {` make this a promise already?

Comment: No, the arrow doesn't make anything a promise, it's just a function syntax. Sure, the `then` method creates another promise (regardless what syntax you use to define a function to pass as a callback), but you are not doing anything with that promise. You need to `return` it from `addToFlatList`.

Comment: @Bergi see updated post, still doesn't work

Comment: Returning the `(dispatch) => {` with `return` doesn't change anything, your arrow function already did that implicitly. But *that* function must return the promise you are creating with the database call!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must return the promise:

```
const addToFlatList = (photoId, photoObj) => (dispatch) => { 
    return database.ref('users').child(photoObj.author).once('value').then((userSnapshot) => {
//  ^^^^^^
        var userInfo = userSnapshot.val();
        return dispatch({type: "GOT_USER", payload: userInfo});
    }).catch(error => {
        return dispatch({type: "GOT_ERROR"});
    });
};
```

Alternatively, you must await the promise so that your `async` function doesn't end prematurely:

```
const addToFlatList = (photoId, photoObj) => async (dispatch) => { 
    try {
        const userSnapshot = await database.ref('users').child(photoObj.author).once('value');
//                           ^^^^^
        var userInfo = userSnapshot.val();
        return dispatch({type: "GOT_USER", payload: userInfo});
    } catch(error) {
        return dispatch({type: "GOT_ERROR"});
    }
}
```

Comment: addToFlatList is still only called once in both approaches

Comment: Note that I am calling addToFlatList like this: 
`photosSnapshot.forEach(async function(childSnapshot) { await addToFlatList(childSnapshot.key, childSnapshot.val())(dispatch); });` see original question

Comment: [Don't use `forEach` with `async`/`await`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/1048572)

Comment: I am following the Firebase doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#foreach

For each is on the `childSnapshot`

Comment: There may be a better way, but I ended up creating a temporary array to hold the result of `for each`, since Firebase only works with `for each`, then iterated through the temp array. It's not space efficient, but it works. Can't find a better alternative at the moment

Comment: @JAM A nice way to do this: `const allPromises = []; data.forEach( x => allPromises.push(x.myAsyncFunction(...))); await Promise.all(allPromises)` - this will start all calls in parallel and continue once they are all resolved

Comment: @Falco performance wise, doing that is still pretty inefficient right? Because I basically have to go through all the data twice, first time when adding to the promise array, second time calling my `addToFlatList ` function

Comment: @JAM No. Falco's solution is `const allPromises = []; data.forEach(childSnapshot => { allPromises.push(addToFlatList(childSnapshot.key, childSnapshot.val())(dispatch)); }); await Promise.all(allPromises);` for your case

Comment: @Bergi how is allPromises used? It is declared then you are just doing `await Promise.all(allPromises);`

Comment: @JAM And in between, I am pushing the promises that `addToFlatList(…)(…)` returns to the array.

Comment: @Bergi But this will not preserve the order of calling `addToFlatList`. Because `addToFlatList ` may not finish before the next one is pushed onto the `allPromises` array

Comment: @JAM Yes it will preserve the order of calls. When their async tasks finish is not important, we have `Promise.all` to cover for that. Of course the calls don't wait for each other, but that's not what you wanted anyway, right? If you need to process them sequentially, then yes there is no way around collecting them in an array before processing them, as `forEach` doesn't support asynchronous iteration.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to have to processed sequentially because I want to sort by photo's post date. I guess Firebase needs to be improved. I don't understand why they only support looping over childSnapshots with forEach

Comment: Can't you still sort after fetching all the post dates? And yes, you might want to change the query so that firebase already returns the results in the expected order.

Comment: I am already getting the results "in expected order" from firebase, but I have to use `forEach` to actually render them in order. See this explaination: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33897213/10906478

Comment: @JAM - you could change your function addToFlatList to include an index and use forEach( (value, index) => addToFlatList(..., index) ) - then the order in which the functions resolve will not matter, since each element will be inserted exactly in the right spot. Then you will get the benefits parallel execution without having to sort again.

Comment: @Falco can you put this into an answer, it's a bit hard to understand